# how to use / add paypal instead of razorpay in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, paypal, django-views

how to use paypal instead of razorpay in this code .. my code

checkout.py :

```
@login_required(login_url= '/login')
def checkout(request,slug):
    course = Course.objects.get(slug = slug)
    
    user = request.user
    action = request.GET.get('action')
    order = None
    payment = None
    error = None
    if action == 'create_payment':
        try:
            user_course = UserCourse.objects.get(user = user , course = course)
            error = "Your are alrady enrolled in this course"
        except:
            pass
        if error is None:
            amount = int((course.price - ( course.price * course.discount * 0.01 )) *100)
            currency = "INR"
            notes = {
                "email":user.email,
                "user":f"{user.first_name} {user.last_name}"

            }
            reciept = f"creativecoders{int(time())}"
            order = client.order.create(
                    {'receipt' :reciept , 
                    'notes' : notes , 
                    'amount' : amount ,
                    'currency' : currency
                    }
                )
            payment = Payment()
            payment.user = user
            payment.course = course
            payment.order_id = order.get('id')
            payment.save()
    data = {
        "course":course,
        "order":order,
        "payment":payment,
        "user":user,
        "error":error,
        
    }
    return render(request,'courses\checkout.html',data)

# function for verify payment 
@csrf_exempt
def verifypayment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        context = {}
        try:
            client.utility.verify_payment_signature(data)
            razorpay_order_id = data['razorpay_order_id']
            razorpay_payment_id = data['razorpay_payment_id']

            payment = Payment.objects.get(order_id = razorpay_order_id)
            payment.payment_id  = razorpay_payment_id
            payment.status =  True
            
            userCourse = UserCourse(user = payment.user , course = payment.course)
            userCourse.save()

            payment.user_course = userCourse
            payment.save()

            return redirect('mycourse')

        except:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid Payment Details")
```

I want to use pay-pal and save the rest of the codes , in `verifypayment` what should i edit to active paypal any help please

- with razorpay everything work perfect , i think i must edit verifypayment but i don't have any idea about how to do this

is there codes may help me with that

Comment: You'll need to edit additional things to handle a successful payment, not just that verifypayment function. And PayPal does not support INR currency.

Comment: okay thanks , can you help me more with some info or codes

Comment: i will change INR currency to USD

Answer (score 0):

Use the newest Python-Checkout-SDK for the v2/checkout/orders API.

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Whatever invokes "verifypayment" will need to invoke displaying that flow instead. When that flow is done, it should proceed to whatever comes after "verifypayment" resulting in a successful payment.